# get IDS of inputs inside in the thead tag of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weird problem, how can i get the id of all the inputs inside my thead of my table, i don´t know how to do it.

This is some code that i have

```
<table id="table_id" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="table-head">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Company
            </th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Target Price<br>
                <input id="targetpriceinput" type="number" value="0" placeholder="set min" style="width:100px;">
            </th>
            <th>Upside<br>
                <input id="upsideeinput" type="number" value="0" placeholder="set min" style="width:100px;">
            </th>
            <th>Price<br>
                <input id="upsideeinput" type="number" value="0" placeholder="set min" style="width:100px;">
            </th>
            <th>Mkt Cap</th>
            <th>Price Performance 1M</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I am noob to javascript and jquery, if you can help me that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get element by id table

get all child nodes > keep checking child nodes until you find input attribute.

get all children with tag name input

for Each input thead child get attribute id. 

the logic above will get you the path below.

`document.getElementById("table_id").children[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[7].childNodes[3].id; // output is "targetpriceinput"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one  element, then you can use it as a selector:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('thead input');
const ids = [... inputs].map(i => i.id);
console.log(ids);
```

Note that you will have empty values if you have inputs without an id